# split string into list based on names regex python

Tags: python, python-re

Looking for a regex which can split the following string into list so that I can loop over and extract the values.
I tried this but it didn't work.

[Download the PDF file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NiWGJ_fgk7wzvPjtAqT8I1e7wiiRwTyt/view?usp=sharing)

```
\b[0-9]+ [A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+(.*?)\b[0-9]+ [A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]
```

**Sample string**

```
string = '''1 Acone Raffaele
^Eboli (SA) - 04/12/1971^ 148/A Dottore commercialista^ 84043 Agropoli (SA) - Via P. Mascagni, 5
^CNARFL71T04D390R^ A - Commercialisti^ Laurea in Economia e Commercio (64/S)
^Agropoli (SA) Ordine Tel. 0974824169 - Fax 0974824169 Esercente
^06/05/2002^06/05/2002^ Email: raffaeleacone@tiscali.it
^06/05/2002^Revisore legale - n. 125741^PEC: raffaele.acone@pec.commercialisti.it

2 Agresta sdfsdf dfdsf
^Salerno (SA) - 08/09/1979 269/A Dottore commercialista^ 84043 Agropoli (SA) - Via F. Angrisani, 7
^GRSDNL79P08H703B^ A - Commercialisti^ Laurea in Economia e Commercio (64/S)
^Agropoli (SA)Tel. 0974 823625 - Fax 0974 823625^ Esercente
^25/07/2012^25/07/2012^ Email: d.agresta@yahoo.it
^25/07/2012^Revisore legale - n. 165766^PEC: d.agresta@pec.it

3 Agresta Veronica
^Vallo della Lucania (SA) - 06/10/1981 281/A Dottore commercialista^ 84052 Ceraso (SA) - Via Campo, 1
^GRSVNC81R46L628Z^ A - Commercialisti^ Laurea in Economia e Commercio (LM-56)
^Ceraso (SA)^Tel. 0974 61248^Esercente
^24/01/2014^24/01/2014^ Email: veronica.ag@live.it
^24/01/2014^Revisore legale - n. 172086^PEC: veronicaagresta@pec.it

'''
```

**Expected Output:**

```
['1 Acone Raffaele
^Eboli (SA) - 04/12/1971^ 148/A Dottore commercialista^ 84043 Agropoli (SA) - Via P. Mascagni, 5
^CNARFL71T04D390R^ A - Commercialisti^ Laurea in Economia e Commercio (64/S)
^Agropoli (SA) Ordine Tel. 0974824169 - Fax 0974824169 Esercente
^06/05/2002^06/05/2002^ Email: raffaeleacone@tiscali.it
^06/05/2002^Revisore legale - n. 125741^PEC: raffaele.acone@pec.commercialisti.it'], 
['Agresta sdfsdf dfdsf
^Salerno (SA) - 08/09/1979 269/A Dottore commercialista^ 84043 Agropoli (SA) - Via F. Angrisani, 7
^GRSDNL79P08H703B^ A - Commercialisti^ Laurea in Economia e Commercio (64/S)
^Agropoli (SA)Tel. 0974 823625 - Fax 0974 823625^ Esercente
^25/07/2012^25/07/2012^ Email: d.agresta@yahoo.it
^25/07/2012^Revisore legale - n. 165766^PEC: d.agresta@pec.it'], 
['3 Agresta Veronica
^Vallo della Lucania (SA) - 06/10/1981 281/A Dottore commercialista^ 84052 Ceraso (SA) - Via Campo, 1
^GRSVNC81R46L628Z^ A - Commercialisti^ Laurea in Economia e Commercio (LM-56)
^Ceraso (SA)^Tel. 0974 61248^Esercente
^24/01/2014^24/01/2014^ Email: veronica.ag@live.it
^24/01/2014^Revisore legale - n. 172086^PEC: veronicaagresta@pec.it']
```

Comment: Is the regex a requirement or are you open to other ideas to get your output?

Comment: I am open to ideas. I need to convert each company data into a list so that I can loop and extract each result.

Comment: So there is always a blank line between company data?

Comment: You can download the PDF file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NiWGJ_fgk7wzvPjtAqT8I1e7wiiRwTyt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Robert try using `companies = string.split('\n\n')`

Answer (score 1):

if there is always a blank line between the companies, than this could be a solution:

```
company_list = [ [company_string] for company_string in string.split('\n\n') if company_string is not '' ]
```